# Посчитать общую сумму товаров в заказе, SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE mobs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, description TEXT, cost INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE orders (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, order_date DATE);

CREATE TABLE mobs_orders(order_id INT NOT NULL, mob_id INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id), FOREIGN KEY (mob_id) REFERENCES mobs(id));

INSERT INTO mobs (name, description, cost)
VALUES
  ('Samsung S6', 'Display: 5.2, CPU: 2.2, RAM: 3 GB, Storage: 128 GB', 800),
  ('Meizu Pro 5', 'Display: 5.5, CPU: 2.5, RAM: 4 GB, Storage: 64 GB', 500),
  ('Meizu Pro 6', 'Display: 5.2, CPU: 2.4, RAM: 4 GB, Storage: 64 GB', 450),
  ('Meizu MX6', 'Display: 5.5, CPU: 2.5, RAM: 4 GB, Storage: 32 GB', 280),
  ('Xiaomi MI 5', 'Display: 5.4, CPU: 2, RAM: 3 GB, Storage: 128 GB', 430),
  ('Samsung S7', 'Display: 5 CPU: 2.5, RAM: 6 GB, Storage: 128 GB', 1000),
  ('Samsung J2', 'Display: 5 CPU: 1.8, RAM: 2 GB, Storage: 32 GB', 200),
  ('Samsung A8', 'Display: 5 CPU: 2, RAM: 3 GB, Storage: 64 GB', 240),
  ('Samsung A10', 'Display: 5 CPU: 2, RAM: 2 GB, Storage: 32 GB', 340),
  ('Samsung 7 Note', 'Display: 5 CPU: 2.4, RAM: 4 GB, Storage: 256 GB', 700),
  ('Samsung A508', 'Display: 5 CPU: 2.4, RAM: 4 GB, Storage: 256 GB', 140),
  ('Samsung B1', 'Display: 5 CPU: 2.4, RAM: 4 GB, Storage: 256 GB', 200);

INSERT INTO orders (order_date)
VALUES
  ('2016-09-11'),
  ('2016-09-15'),
  ('2016-09-23'),
  ('2016-10-25'),
  ('2016-10-29'),
  ('2016-11-01'),
  ('2016-11-01'),
  ('2016-11-02'),
  ('2016-11-02'),
  ('2016-11-03'),
  ('2016-11-03'),
  ('2016-11-04'),
  ('2016-11-05'),
  ('2016-11-05'),
  ('2016-11-06'),
  ('2016-11-06'),
  ('2016-11-07'),
  ('2016-11-08'),
  ('2016-11-08'),
  ('2016-11-08');

INSERT INTO mobs_orders VALUES
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 5),
(4, 12),
(4, 6),
(4, 6),
(4, 6),
(4, 6),
(4, 6),
(4, 6),
(5, 9),
(6, 2),
(7, 5),
(7, 8),
(8, 1),
(9, 6),
(9, 8),
(9, 8),
(10, 8),
(11, 8),
(12, 8),
(13, 8),
(14, 8),
(14, 8),
(15, 8),
(15, 8),
(16, 8),
(17, 8),
(18, 8),
(18, 8),
(19, 8),
(20, 8);
```

А вот сам запрос

```
SELECT
  mobs_orders.order_id,
  mobs_orders.mob_id AS 'Mob ID',
  mobs.name AS 'Phone',
  orders.order_date AS 'Order date',
  (SELECT SUM(mobs.cost) FROM mobs WHERE mobs_orders.mob_id = mobs.id AND order_id  = mobs_orders.order_id)

  FROM mobs, orders
JOIN mobs_orders ON mob_id = mobs.id

                  AND order_id = orders.id
  WHERE orders.order_date BETWEEN DATE('NOW', '-7 day') AND DATE ('NOW')
```

Первые 2 таблицы понятны. 3 - это id заказа и id модели товара в заказе.
Получается лишь сумма определенной единицы товара, как найти сумму всех единиц товара за заказ?
А так же нужно как-то будет выбрать заказы за неделю, сумма которых > 500. Сейчас там просто сумма за неделю.

[image: результат вызова]

Answer (score 4):

Первая задача решается использованием join'ов, группировки и агрегации:

```
SELECT o.order_date, SUM(m.cost) AS total_cost
FROM mobs_orders AS mo
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON mo.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN mobs AS m ON mo.mob_id = m.id
GROUP BY o.order_date;
```

Вторая использование подзапроса и функции `strftime`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT o.order_date, SUM(m.cost) AS total_cost
    FROM mobs_orders AS mo
    INNER JOIN orders AS o ON mo.order_id = o.id
    INNER JOIN mobs AS m ON mo.mob_id = m.id
    GROUP BY o.order_date
)
WHERE total_cost > 500 AND strftime('%W', order_date) = strftime('%W', 'now');
-- или, если нужны данные не за текущую неделю, а последние 7 дней
WHERE total_cost > 500 AND order_date > (SELECT DATETIME('now', '-7 day');
```